# Grails / Compilation error when running: "FilterManager.groovy: 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 1

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, build

The project I'm trying to run is in `Grail 2.3.5` and I upgrade it to `2.4.4` version.

Now, when I trying to run it using my IntelliJ I get this error:

> ...\target\work\plugins\webxml-1.4.1\src\groovy\grails\plugin\webxml\FilterManager.groovy: 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 1.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: The file is not really a text file now.  May be corrupted.  Could you check it a hex editor (say http://www.hexedit.com/).

Comment: @Jayan Thanks for your comment. I deleted my ide's project source code and replaced it with a new one because I cannot wait long.

Comment: You should investigate why you reached that state.  Every error is opportunity for learning some thing.  You may delete the question as there is no use to a visitor in future..

Comment: @Jayan Believe it or not, a future visitor did find this question useful.  I had been getting this error on another platform that uses groovy scripts, Jenkins, and was unable to resolve it until your comment and other pages made me realize I had a corrupted file; I subsequently deleted it and created a new one.  I think it may be safe to conclude this user also had a corrupted file.